# Why did Katia wait to get branded with John Wick?

Tags: plot-explanation, john-wick-chapter-4

In *John Wick Chapter 4* (2023), The Ruska Roma welcomes back John Wick and accepts his High Table duel
with Marquis. Then, John Wick and Katia had their arms branded with the
family crest symbol at the same time.

[image]

Why did Katia wait to get branded with John Wick?

Comment: Presumably the simultaneous branding is part of the ritual of mending someone's ticket. Possibly representative of her taking on the responsibility for bringing Wick back into the fold. It might not be standard to brand everyone in this way.